# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, cx_Oracle, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cx-oracle, pyproject.toml

in another computer it works good, I installed de dependecies and i didn't have problems, but in this computer, in this virtual envviroment (which i don't think is the problem) don't work.
Im on python 3.8, in my another computer didn't gives me any problems with the same version. I don't understand what is going on.

I tried install both separetly, but it gives me the same error, i tried to install pandas with `pip install pandas==1.3.5` and cx_Oracle with `pip install cx_Oracle`, so i don't think the version is the problem